# Two State Linear Actuator

Tags: actuator

I need two state linear actuator. You can have a look at the picture to understand what I mean.

Don't care about the hand !

[image: mit inform project]
<sub>(source: [robaid.com](https://www.robaid.com/wp-content/gallery/mit/mit-inform-system-1.jpg))</sub>

I need to electrically move the things like this squares up and down. Bidirectional linear actuators are needed.
What is the cheapest and tiniest actuator (or sth else) that I can use to move this squares up and down. There are just two states ('up','down'). Don't care how much higher a square rises, when it is up.

Comment: The question isn't clear.  Presumably a user uses a finger to press a button.  What is the "two state linear actuator" supposed to do?  Also, what's the bigger picture?  Ie, what is your overall goal?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a solenoid.

Comment: Short and to teh point, Ian :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple if you are using a coil and a pin (solenoid) but the size (diameter) of the coil would be the limiting factor to how closely your pins could be nested. Pneumatics (pressure= up and vacuum = down) could also be used and achieve a tighter nesting.  The valve configuration would be the limiting factor with pneumatics.